# How to convert ArrayList to JSON object

Tags: java, json, arraylist

```
public ArrayList<String> convertJsonToJsonObject(){

    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String> ();

    mylist.add("abc");
    mylist.add("cfd");
    mylist.add("ert");
    mylist.add("fg");
    mylist.add("ujk");
    mylist.add("wer");

    mylist.add("dvb");
    mylist.add("ert");


    System.out.println("JSONObject :: "+(JSONObject)JSONSerializer.toJson(mylist));
}
```

I am having error at `.toJson()` method, I am not sure what is the mistake I am making.

Comment: 1. What does the error say ? 2. Which Json library are you using ?

Answer (score 23):

You can use the [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) library to accomplish this.

```
 ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String> ();
 mylist.add("abc");
 mylist.add("cfd");
 mylist.add("ert");
 mylist.add("fg");
 mylist.add("ujk");
 String json = new Gson().toJson(mylist);
```

You can refer to the [GSON User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for more support.

Comment: **Be sure to include the GSON library in your project!**

Comment: i am trying to convert the array into json object.JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(mylist);
  System.out.println("print the array" + jsArray);
  for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
   jsArray.put(mylist.get(i));
  }
  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  System.out.println("print he object" + obj);

Answer (score 9):

```
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(mylist);
```

Or

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonArray = gson.toJson(mylist);
```

Get [java-json.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavajsonjar.htm) and [Gson.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.2) here

Comment: i got the output in array["acb ", "adg ", "tyy " ].Now i would like to convert the json array to json object.is there any way i can do it?

Comment: Hi whatever you are getting it is the json object

Comment: Did you understand the concept now may be you were confused because it was not key value pair [Read this](http://json.org/) you will understand it

Answer (score 3):

```
gson.toJson(object);
```

[Gson Google Group](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: It says,The method toJson(ArrayList<String>) is undefined for the type Object.@Peter Liljenberg

Comment: `List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<> (); myList.add("hello"); System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(mylist));`

Comment: Oh, i understand. I give you link to Google Code of this library, you have to download it and add to dependency of your project.

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayList<Domain> list = new ArrayList<Domain>();
list.add(new Domain());
list.add(new Domain());
list.add(new Domain());
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
```

Comment: Can U say how to retrive back the values in list?

Comment: @ArunJoshla List<Domain> videos = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Domain>>(){}.getType());  ,  json is string value that initialized last line of answer

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> bibo = new ArrayList<String>();
bibo.add("obj1");
bibo.add("obj2");
bibo.add("obj3");
String json = new Gson().toJson(bibo);
```