# Column wise search giving "227200:101 Uncaught TypeError: otable.api().columns is not a function" error in JQuery dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using jquery-1.6.4.min.js and jquery.dataTables.min.js for jquery datatable.
And  I am getting an error as:

```
Uncaught TypeError: otable.api is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (227200:100)
at Object.resolveWith (jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.C (jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2)
```

And I cannot use DataTable with capital **D** because I am using dataTable with **d** across my whole application.

Below is my JavaScript code, the data is coming from ajax call

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
     var otable =  $('#sectionList').dataTable({ 
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "bFilter": true,
      "bSearchable": false,
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 10,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "sAjaxSource": "<c:url value='/group/${groupVO.groupNum}/load' />",
      "sDom": '<"H"lfr<"headerTitle">>t<"F"ip>',
      "fnDrawCallback":function() {
       $parent = $(this).parent();
       $parent.css("min-height", "0px");
      },
      "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
       $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html('<a href="/CMSWeb/group/${groupVO.groupNum}/section/' + aData.sectionNumber + '">' + aData.sectionNumber + '</a>');
       $('td:eq(5)', nRow).html("<span class='" + aData.sectionStatus.toLowerCase() + "'>" + aData.sectionStatus + "</span>");
             return nRow;
         }, 
      "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
       $(".headerTitle").html("<span>Sections List</span>");
      },
      "aoColumns": [
       { "mDataProp": "sectionNumber" },
       { "mDataProp": "sectionDesc" },
       { "mDataProp": "poolCode" },
       { "mDataProp": "poolDescription" },
       { "mDataProp": "contractTypes" },
       { "mDataProp": "sectionStatus" }
      ],
     });
    
     $('#sectionList tfoot th').each( function (i) {
            var title = $('#sectionList thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );        
        } );
     
        otable.api().columns().every( function () {
           var that = this;
           $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
               if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                   that
                       .search( this.value )
                       .draw();
               }
           });
        });
```

Comment: Try to move otable.api() call inside fnInitComplete function. Follow the example: https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Comment: Still getting the same error